# .NET 4 Memory Mapped Files

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, shared-memory

Does anyone know for sure if when you pull from MMF, does the local App process create it's own memory storage for the contents in the shared memory? or does it reference the memory directly?

I ask this question because I am in thinking about using a 4gb file in MMF, and if it pulls down local memory for each app(process) that uses the resource, I will be looking at a lot of RAM.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two kinds of memory mappings. The most common one is the shared mapping that you obtain by `MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(string)`. Shared mappings usually use the IO cache memory pages to hold the file content and map those pages in the virtual address space of those processes that access the corresponding part of the mapped file. It only consumes as much memory as the total size of the resident parts of the file. And since there is a physical medium where this content comes from/goes to, the OS can free this memory whenever it is running low on memory (by writing the dirty pages to the disk before that).

There is another mapping type, know as private or CoW (Copy-on-Write) mapping. Initially it works very much like the shared mapping but when any process writes to any part of it, a new memory page, private to this process, is created and the content of the original page is copied into it (hence the *copy* on *write*). This new memory page is private to the process and is not backed up by the original file but rather by the system page file. So private mappings consume additional memory and changes made by one process are not visible in the other processes. Private mappings are created using `MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(path, mode, map, capacity, access)` with `access` set to `System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFileAccess.CopyOnWrite`.

Answer (score 1):

Mapped memory is not copied in. It is demand loaded and also demand unloaded.

Just mapping it does nothing. You only load what you access and the OS can unload memory whenever it decides it is the right thing to do.

Also memory for the same mapped file is shared between processes.

Comment: any input on memory mapping objects?

Comment: What about it? If it is a different question, you'd be better off asking a new one.